# TensorFlow saved_model returning same result for different inputs

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to export a saved model using the code below. It exports the saved_model.pb, but for any input that I give it, I get the same result. I think there is something wrong with how I am doing the output. I am very new to TensorFlow, so I apologize if this is a simple mistake.

```
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

def export_model(saved_model_dir, final_tensor_name):
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    with sess.graph.as_default() as graph:
      tf.saved_model.simple_save(
        sess,
        saved_model_dir,
        inputs={'image': tf.placeholder(tf.string)},
        outputs={'prediction': graph.get_tensor_by_name(final_tensor_name + ":0")}
   )
```

I am also using the retrain.py from the following tutorial: https://github.com/BartyzalRadek/Multi-label-Inception-net so it could be something from there.

How I have structured my code is that I have included this in a separate file so I don’t need to retrain every time I want to try to save.

Comment: Can you provide the the code for Inference Request, where you are providing the Inputs. Also, it may be helpful if you provide the Output. (Only if the Inputs and Output are not Confidential)

Comment: Also, can you run the command,                                                         saved_model_cli show --dir path_to_saved_model --all.                                                      From that command, we can understand if the SignatureDefs are proper.

Comment: It will be because of the value of final_tensor_name. Is it the actual Predicted Output?